# Application Event fired by a child component doesn't flow down other child component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have 1 main component (Parent.cmp) which includes 2 components (Brother1.cmp and Brother2.cmp).

Brother1 fires an event which should cause an action in Brother2.

Documentation says that we should use APPLICATION events for that:

> Application events follow a traditional publish-subscribe model. An application event is fired from an instance of a component. All components that provide a handler for the event are notified.

I've created an APPLICATION event and fire it from Brother1. According to the documentation, I expect the event to be distributed to Brother2. It is handled by Parent.cmp, but it never gets to Brother2.

What I tried:

1. as the Parent.cmp receives the Brother1 event, I tried to fire a new Parent_evt APPLICATION event hoping it will be dispatched to Brother2. No success.
2. The expression `var brother1Event = $A.get("e.c:Brother1_evt");` doesn't work in my code, and even doesn't seem to be firing any event at all.

What am I missing ?

Thank you for your help.

Components code below:

**TestEvents.app**:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:Parent/>
</aura:application>
```

**Parent.cmp**

```
<aura:handler name="Brother1_evt" event="c:Brother1_evt" action="{!c.handleBrother1_evt}" />

<aura:attribute name="message" type="string" />
Parent message: <ui:outputtext value="{!v.message}" />

<div>
    <c:Brother1/>
</div>

<div>
    <c:Brother2/>
</div>
```

**ParentController.js**:

```
({
handleBrother1_evt : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set( "v.message", "Brother1 event Received");
}
```

})

**Brother1.cmp**

```
<aura:component >

<aura:registerEvent name="Brother1_evt" type="c:Brother1_evt" />

<aura:attribute name="message" type="string" />
<aura:handler name="Brother1_evt" event="c:Brother1_evt" action="{!c.handleBrother1_evt}" />

<lightning:button label="Click Me to fire an event from Brother 1!" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleBrother1Click}" />
<br/>
Brother 1 message: <ui:outputText value="{!v.message}" />
```

**Brother1_evt.evt**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" />
```

**Brother1Controller.js**

```
({
handleBrother1Click : function(component, event, helper) {

    var brother1Event = component.getEvent("Brother1_evt");
    brother1Event.fire();
},

handleBrother1_evt : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set( "v.message", "Brother1 event Received");
}
```

**Brother2.cmp**

```
<aura:component >

<aura:handler name="Brother1_evt" event="c:Brother1_evt" action="{!c.handleBrother1_evt}" />

<aura:attribute name="message" type="string" />
Brother 2 message: <ui:outputText value="{!v.message}" />
```

**Brother2Controller.js**

```
({

handleBrother1_evt : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set( "v.message", "Brother1 event Received");
}
```

})

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Can you try removing name attribute from the handler as the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_example.htm) quotes _The handler for an application event won’t work if you set the name attribute in `<aura:handler>`. Use the name attribute only when you’re handling component events._

Comment: @codeyinthecloud That really should have been an answer. Also, it's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_handling.htm):

> The handler for an application event won’t work if you set the name attribute in `<aura:handler>`. Use the name attribute only when you’re handling component events.

You need to remove the "name" attribute.

Comment: +1 You beat me by seconds!

Comment: Yes. It works. Many thanks.

I promise to read the documentation with greater attention in the future.

NB: sorry for the late response. I was sick in the last days.